# How to Compare Spark Dataframe on different Sources

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, google-cloud-dataproc

My usecase has requirement to migrate the data from AWS to Google Cloud Dataproc cluster upon which as a DataQuality check I need to compare the source and destination data for which I am trying to create spark Data frames and then compare the difference.

The problem I am facing is the data is on different cluster and for comparing I need the data frames to be on the same cluster.

Is there any feasible solution to achieve this?